# MySQL & PHP Loop with a twist

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I can't wrap my head around how I need to go about this. I have a table (tbl_accolade) and in it are several columns they are rep_name, accolade_text, and customer_name. I am tring to loop them on a page but in a special format. Sometimes there are multiple accolades for each rep. I want them looped together which wouldn't be hard if I ordered them that way however I want a header with the reps name but I don't want it to repeat for example:

```
Jonny B Rep

Customer Accolade 1
Customer Name 1

Customer Accolade 2
Customer Name 2

Customer Accolade 3
Customer Name 3

Victoria S Rep

Customer Accolade 4
Customer Name 4
```

I am not sure how to even start this. Does anyone know a good direction to start in?

Comment: Did you try something yourself? If yes, SHOW US YOUR CODE!

Comment: I don't understand: why can't you order by the rep name in your query?

Comment: @EisaAdil No I haven't started anything because I know what I would try is not what I want.

Comment: @Barmar I can order but I don't want the reps name repeated each time. The reps name is in the same table as each accolade.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't properly structure your database tables. You have a one-to-many relationship of one rep to many accolades.

Comment: Use a query that orders by rep_name. When you're looping over the results, check if the rep name in the same as the previous row. When it changes, display the header for the new rep name.

Comment: Each accolade has an ID number. That ID is unique.

Comment: @Barmar that sounds exactly what I need to do. In the loop statement how do I could it to check for the change?

Comment: I can't believe I have to explain this almost on a daily basis, it's so utterly trivial; I sometimes think if you can't figure it out yourself you should give up on programming. You have a variable that contains the last rep name. Each time through the loop, you compare the current rep name to the variable. If they're different, you display the new header, and then set the variable to the current rep name.

Comment: I am actually not a programmer I had this thrusted on to me because no one else wanted to do it and I was on vacation. I have been able to figure out quite a lot on myself thank you. I understand it maybe frusting for someone who has done this since the 80's but if you don't want to teach why on your on a site answering questions? I will try to write the code for this and post what I come up with to help others.

Comment: And here are two that served me well in the past when I started learning MySQL: http://www.sqlcourse.com/ and http://www.sqlcourse2.com/ ENjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point in the right direction.

It seems that you just want to order by `rep_name` alphabetically, so use `ORDER BY rep_name ASC`, like this:

```
SELECT rep_name, customer_name FROM tbl_accolade
ORDER BY rep_name ASC
```

Then in your PHP, while looping through your results, have something like this:

```
$last_rep = "";
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    if ($last_rep != $row['rep_name']) {
        echo '<p><strong>- '.$row['rep_name'].'</strong></p>';
        $last_rep = $row['rep_name'];
    }
    echo '<p>Customer: '.$row['customer_name'].'</p>';
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
- Adam Smith
Customer: Pete Jones
Customer: David Watson
- Barry Jenkins
Customer: Harry Hill
Customer: Julie Dawes
- Caroline Beal
Customer: Pete Jones
Customer: David Watson
- Carl Dickson
Customer: Sally Bean
Customer: Tom Daley
```

You could even add another `ORDER BY` condition to sort the order of customers under each rep.

```
SELECT rep_name, customer_name FROM tbl_accolade
ORDER BY rep_name ASC, customer_name ASC
```

Comment: Ok excellent, I was able to try something similar but mine does have the `$sth->fetch()) ` I have `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`